# Wait for event so long as other event hasn't fired

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous

I have an async method where I would like to block execution until 2 seconds after the `OnLeave` event of a control is fired, but only if the `OnEnter` event is not fired in the meantime.

In other words, if the `OnLeave` event is fired and then `OnEnter` fires 1 sec after, it should wait for another `OnLeave` + another 2 seconds without the `OnEnter` firing again before returning back to my method.

This should also implement a timeout and I looked at using a Task.WaitAll() with a timeout, but just not quite sure how to do the first part because of the dependency on both events.

Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Comment: You can implement synchronization (see [`Monitor.Enter`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_MonitorEnter_and_MonitorExit)), task chaining (see Task.ContinueWith), but from usage scenario it seems you rather need a working thread which does that `OnEnter`/`OnLeave` pairs synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Control {
    public EventHandler OnEnter;
    public EventHandler OnLeave;

    public void TriggerEnter() {
        if (OnEnter != null) {
            OnEnter(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void TriggerLeave() {
        if (OnLeave != null) {
            OnLeave(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    public static EventHandler OnBufferedEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        bool hasEntered = false;
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000);
        OnBufferedEvent += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("My buffered event has fired");

        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>{
            if (!hasEntered) {
                if (OnBufferedEvent != null) {
                    OnBufferedEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        };

        Control control = new Control {
            OnEnter = (sender, eventArgs) => {
                hasEntered = true;
                Console.WriteLine("On enter event has fired");
            },
            OnLeave = (sender, eventArgs) => {
                hasEntered = false;
                timer.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("On leave event has fired");
            }
        };

        control.TriggerLeave();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        control.TriggerEnter();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        control.TriggerLeave();
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
    }
}
```

Another, more exotic solution, would be using Rx to buffer events and do observation logic on them.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229241(v=vs.103).aspx) provides some more explanations but you will have to create observable collections out of both Enter and Leave events and mix them up together. Not a trivial task.